# Simulating a time series including a shock

Tags: r, time-series, arima, simulation, lags

I want to simulate a time series in R, following an ARMA(1,0) model in the form $Y_t = Y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$, shocking it at time 20.
In a few words, I therefore have to input $\epsilon_{20} = 30$ (the shock magnitude).

Now, I am using the `arima.sim` function as it is the one I'm familiar with for simulating a time series, but I am not sure on how to implement a shock into it.

Let's start with a standard simulation, based on 250 observations:

```
shocksim <- arima.sim(n=250, list(ar = c(0.5)))
```

How can I input the shock in such a simulation?

Comment: Did you perhaps mean "shocking it at time 20" instead of "shocking it at lag 20"?

Comment: Uhm, I see what you mean. Yeah, that's probably the correct way to say it in words.
Anyway, ϵ20=30 is what I mean.

Comment: I changed "lag" to "time".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
n <- 250
innovs <- rnorm(n)
innovs[20] <- 30
y <- arima.sim(n=n,innov=innovs, list(ar = c(0.5)))
```

Plotting a trajectory yields

[image]

Note your code says you want an AR(1) process with coefficient 0.5 while the text specifies a random walk. I did the former.

Comment: Thank you very much.
You're right, I didn't think about that. Actually, I need to represent it in the form Yt=Yt−1+ϵt, with the innovation distributed as GWN(0,1).

Comment: Just replace the last line with `y <- cumsum(innovs)`

Comment: It sure did! I did, but it doesn't show up, probably because of limitation on my newly created account.